# Maximize function of vector given normalization condition.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question about maximizing a function of a vector given a condition.

The function in question is shown below.

$$
f(\vec{p}) = ( T \vec{p}) \space \cdot \space \vec{1} 
$$

where $\vec{p}$ is a column vector of size $ N \times 1 $ and T is matrix of size $N \times N$

The following condition must also be true of the solution.

$$
\vec{p} \space \cdot \space \vec{1} = 1
$$

Where $\vec{1}$ is a column vector of size $N \times 1$ with all of its elements equaling $1$.

For example when $N = 3$,

$
\vec{1} =  \begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\
1 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}
$

So I need to find a vector $\vec{p}$ to maximize $f(\vec{p})$.

Comment: Did you try Lagrange's multiplier?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a particular vector $p$ with $p\cdot\vec1 = 1$ provides the maximum value of $f(p)$ you are after. Let $r$ be any non-zero vector such that $r\cdot\vec 1 = 0$. For example, $r$ could be $[1~~-1~~0~\dots~0]^T$. Note that for any scalar $a$, $ar\cdot\vec 1 = 0$.

Now $$\begin{align}f(p + ar) &= T(p + ar)\cdot\vec 1 \\&= T(p)\cdot\vec 1 + a(T(r)\cdot\vec 1)\\ &= f(p) + af(r)\end{align}$$

If $f(r) \ne 0$, then I can always choose $a$ so that $af(r)$ is positive, contradicting our choice of $p$ to give a maximum. 
Hence, one of the following must hold:

- Either $f$ has no maximum value, or
- for every $r$ with $r\cdot\vec1 = 0, f(r) = 0$. I.e. $T$ carries the plane $r\cdot\vec 1 = 0$ to itself.

Since most linear transformations do not carry the plane $r\cdot\vec 1 = 0$ to itself, for most $T, f$ will not have a maximum value. When $T$ does carry $r\cdot\vec 1 = 0$ to itself, then $f$ is constant on $p\cdot\vec 1$, so any such $p$ will give you the maximum value.